# (2 n) Visual Cryptography using Python

Tags: python, image, algorithm, encryption

I am trying to implement the `simple algorithm` mentioned on wikipedia to create a `(2 n) secret sharing images` using `python`.

> There is a simple algorithm for binary (black and white) visual cryptography that creates 2 encrypted images from an original unencrypted image. The algorithm is as follows: First create an image of random pixels the same size and shape as the original image. Next, create a second image the same size and shape as the first, but where a pixel of the original image is the same as the corresponding pixel in the first encrypted image, set the same pixel of the second encrypted image to the opposite color. Where a pixel of the original image is different than the corresponding pixel in the first encrypted image, set the same pixel of the second encrypted image to the same color as the corresponding pixel of the first encrypted image. The two apparently random images can now be combined using an exclusive-or (XOR) to re-create the original image.

This is my code for generating `share1 and share2`

```
    share1 = Image.new("1", size, "white")
    share1pix = share1.load()
    for i in range(len(self.key)):
        for j in range(255):
            x = randint(0,1)
            if x == 0:
                share1pix[j, i] = 0
    share2 = Image.new("1", size)
    share2pix = share2.load()
    for i in range(len(self.key)):
        for j in range(255):
            if pix[j, i] == share1pix[j, i]:
                if pix[j, i] == 255:
                    share2pix[j, i] = 0
                else:
                    share2pix[j, i] = 255
            else:
                share2pix[j, i] = share1pix[j, i]
```

where `pix` is the original image array. However, I am getting the output as

original image

[image: original image]

share1

[image: share1]

share2

[image: share2]

As you can see, `share2.png` is not random. It is just the reverse of `original.png`. Where am I going wrong? Please help. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little error in your algorithm. The idea is that for each pixel of `pix`, `share1` and `share2`, we have the following relation :

```
share2 = pix XOR share1
```

This translates into :

```
if pix[j, i] == share1[j, i]:
  share2[j, i] = 0
else:
  share2[j, i] = 255
```

Comment: Point noted. Thanks!